# wordpress ajax отображение content

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Задача: есть блок с картинками, которые являются изображениями разных постов WP. Блок `the content();` скрыт в CSS. Необходимо реализовать отображение содержимого соответствующего блока `content` при нажатии на соответствующее изображение.

В последней попытке попытался отобразить скрытый `div` c `content` помимо ошибки, нарвался еще и на эту ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)

Очень прошу, подскажите как все же это можно реализовать?

```js
$(".show-more").click(function(){
                                $(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").slideToggle('fast',
                                    function() {
                                        if ($(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").length==0) {
                                            $(".show-more").css("display","none");
                                        }
                                    }
                                );
                            })
```

```css
#more_service {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
  while ($gadget->have_posts()) : $gadget->the_post(); ?>
<div class="img-hover">
  <img class="img-responsive img-rounded show-more" id="client" 
        src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"
        alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
</div>

 <div id="more_service">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress использует jQuery в noconflict mode. Использование символа $ приводит к ошибке. Нужно в скрипте либо все символы $ заменить на jQuery

```js
jQuery(".show-more").click(function() {
  jQuery(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").slideToggle('fast',
    function() {
      if (jQuery(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").length == 0) {
        jQuery(".show-more").css("display", "none");
      }
    });
});
```

либо запускать свой скрипт my.js следующего содержания

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".show-more").click(function() {
    $(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").slideToggle('fast',
      function() {
        if ($(document).find(".more_service:not(:visible)").length == 0) {
          $(".show-more").css("display", "none");
        }
      }
    );
  });

  // Прочие действия после загрузки страницы
  
});
```

В этом примере важен аргумент $ в первой строке, он позволяет далее использовать этот символ внутри функции.

Сам скрипт my.js надо запускать из functions.php вашей темы

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my', 'my.js', array('jquery', 'cycle'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
```