# не работает $ с jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

подключаю jquery на wordpress таким образом

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <script>
         console.log($(".row"));
    </script>
```

потом в тэг скрипт делаю тестовый вывод в кончоль и выводит ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):69
(anonymous) @ (index):69
```

если вывожу таким образом, то все работает

```
<script>
         console.log(jquery(".row"));
    </script>
```

эта функция тоже не помогает, если написать ее перед всем кодом

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

помогите, пж

Comment: а если сделать `window['$'] = jQuery;` ?

Comment: Так работает, но мне нужно подключить еще другие файлы с использованием jquery, во всех этих файлах мне тоже надо это прописывать? С чем это вообще может быть связано, раньше такого не было

Comment: @WeB DevelopeR Скорре всего вы подключаете jquery после того как функция исполняется а надо наоборот

Comment: @Arcadiy если бы я подключал jquery после, то он бы вообще не работал в принципе, но он работает только с функцией jquery

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я вставил эту строчку во все файлы, где используется jquery, все заработало, но у меня такое чувство, что это костыля какой то, почитал в интернете, говорят вообще, что в wordpress нельзя использовать $, а только jQuery, правда так?

Comment: @WeB DevelopeR когда то давно прочитал что лучше всегда использовать jQuery вместо $  для избежания конфликтов

Comment: @axmed2004 это понятно, но что делать с библиотеками, которые написаны на jquery и там используется $

Comment: @WeBDevelopeR я избегаю jquery и wordpress, больше вряд ли что посоветую

Comment: а что будет если написать console.log($)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ выводит undefind, а если с той командой, то ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}

Comment: Вы все делаете неправильно. почитайте ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593350/220220

Comment: @KAGGDesign  то есть во все библиотеки, которые используют jquery с $ надо обернуть весь код в эту функцию?

Comment: Ваши файлы надо обернуть в это. И не запускать самому jQuery, WP сам это делает. И использовать зависимости скриптов: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь, на самом деле вся проблема в том, что я пытался выполнить script в head, когда я перенес этот участок кода в footer, то все заработало без всяких команд. Надо быть очень внимательным со своим кодом и не упускать таких мелочей, еще раз всем спасибо!